# iOS QR code scanner that can open URLs in the default browser

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

I am in search for an iOS app that can open URLs in the default browser upon reading a QR-code. All I can find are apps that have their own in-app browsers. That's problematic since many of them are bloated with ads and won't work properly (I am using it for registration).

This seems to be standard on Android, so I really don't know what to look for. So basically, is there maybe some keywords to use to find these apps?

Is it technically possible on iOS for other apps to open up other apps, such as, in this case, the web browser?

Comment: A resounding "yes" is the answer to your direct question at the end. If you're looking for software recommendations, please head to the [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @tubedogg  If the question is not relevant for this site, flag it and the mods will *move* it to the appropriate site.  This way the user avoids cross posting, which, is a no-no.  I am also not seeing why this isn't valid here.

Comment: @Allan The OP has two questions. One, he wants a QR scanner that opens links in Safari. Two, he wants to know if apps can open other apps. His post can be edited to be on-topic here if it focuses on the second question, so it shouldn't be moved (which I was already aware of) but software recommendations are off-topic per the Close pop-up: "...questions asking to recommend or find off-site resources (Mac/book/software/tutorial)".

Comment: @Allan "I am in search for an iOS app [that can do XYZ]. I really don't know what to look for." That is asking for an app recommendation, as is the literal title of the post. The last sentence is related but is a technical question. As far as cross-posting, as I _explicitly_ said in my last comment, I believe the post can be edited to remove the software rec angle and therefore remain here. As far as software recs being on-topic here, see [this](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2426) and [this](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2870) which are both more recent.

Comment: @Allan No, I didn't read the whole three line question. I'm just doing this to troll you because I have nothing better to do with my Saturday afternoon. I'm done discussing anything with you. Please stop bothering me.

Comment: As recommended by the first comment I've already created this post in the Software Recomendations SE... What I understand now, this was a big "no-no"? How do I correct this. Can I remove this post or flag it myself in some way? Edit: I just flagged it.

Answer (score 2):

If the native QR code scanner in control center and the camera app aren’t sufficient, I use https://qrafter.com for this on iOS. The pro version is inexpensive and very useful.

[image]

It's possible to hand off URL - just that it's up to the developer to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 11, opening the default Camera app and pointing it to a QR with a URL will prompt you to open it in Safari.